# Conditional requires with browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, browserify

with browserify, I'm trying to require a module only when in development. For some reason it is always being included in production too.

NPM Scripts:

```
"start": "export NODE_ENV=development&& grunt watch & grunt serve",
"prod": "export NODE_ENV=production&& grunt prod"
```

Component requires:

```
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

require('animation.gsap');

if (!isProduction) {
   require('debug.addIndicators');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

browserify bundles at compile time. So it is unaware of your variables. Check this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/conditionalify. It can solve your problem (though I have not use it) . You can have different context for different environment while bundling.